# Choosing Drum Sticks as per size and wood

Tags: drums, acoustic-drumset

I am a passionate drummer, not so professional, but have a band in my school. I don't focus on any specific kind of songs or beats and have an acoustic drum kit.

I would prefer nylon tip drum sticks, and some kind of wood that would be more of dense. Can someone please recommend me, not a model, but specifications of a drum stick that would be a bit long and satisfy my conditions? Remember, I need a stick that would suit, if not specialise in, all kinds of music. 
Thanks.

Comment: Some sticks aren't that expensive. Your best bet is probably to go to a store, tell them what you are looking for, try out a few sticks, and then buy a few different kinds and play with them and see which feels best to you.

Comment: Weirdly, played a gig last week with a brilliant drummer, and we noticed that each of his pair of (wooden tipped) sticks sounded VERY different on a cymbal. One 'matched' pair, two rather different sounds. So, maybe it's more complex than we think...

Comment: @Tim That could possibly be down to Technique also. As well as how heavily he is hitting the cymbals.

Comment: I don't hit her cymbals that hard and use their matched grip. Now, that's all that I could say in words! Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: @NathanTaylor - no, he's a pro, and I play as well, and the hits were identical. Strange.

Comment: @Tim ah I was thinking he done it deliberately for effect maybe? If not one stick may have been worn out more I tend to notice my lead hand stick degrades faster

Answer (score 1):

You should try Vater's Fusion sticks (http://www.vater.com/#!/product/10) These have a longer shaft than most sticks and for thickness, they are between a 5A and 5B with a ball nylon tip. I find them to have the right balance for attack and speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your typical drumstick is made of Hickory wood which neither that dense nor that light.

Maple is another popular wood for sticks but is lighter than Hickory.

Your best bet would be sticks made out of Oak, which is quite denser than Hickory and a lot denser than Maple; I know for sure Pro-Mark produces oak sticks that come in various specs and sizes.

The typical length for a stick is right around 16", a longer stick would be around 17".

Keep in mind that nylon tip sticks, in comparison to wood tip ones, would sound significantly brighter on the cymbals.

Answer (score 0):

Sticks are very personal things - what might suit you might not suit someone else.
Best thing to do is head to your local drum store, grab a few different pairs (sizes and makes) from the rack and try them out on the pad in the store and see what feels comfortable for you.